# Inject rest router in controller

Tags: loopback, loopback4

I need a route who return all my API routes in an array.
I'm trying to inject rest router to use the method "list" but I get this error:

> The key 'rest.router' is not bound to any value in context RequestContext-y_3kWzd3Ra-inz75ketkRw-5 (context: RequestContext-y_3kWzd3Ra-inz75ketkRw-5, binding: rest.router, resolutionPath: controllers.DiscoveryController --> @DiscoveryController.constructor[0])

My code :

```
export class DiscoveryController {
  constructor(@inject(RestBindings.ROUTER) private readonly router: RestRouter) {}

  @get('/discovery')
  @response(200)
  discovery(): [] {
   console.log(this.router.list());
   return [];
  }

}
```

Does anyone know how to inject router to get all routes or if another method exists ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's file named *openapi-spec.ts* in your loopback4 application.
In that file, there will be a line:

```
const outFile = process.argv[2] ?? '';
```

Change it to:

```
const outFile = process.argv[2] ?? './openapi.json';
```

Then do "*npm run openapi-spec*".
This will create a file named *openapi.json* in your root directory, it has all the details of your existing APIs.

If you want do this at runtime, then add this to your "*prestart*" script.